# Components shows some weird stuff when button is clicked

Tags: java, background, jpanel, jbutton

I'm having problem with my gui, because when I click on any button, something annoying pops in my panel and other component.

[image: image of my gui]

Here's my class that extends JPanel

`public MyPanel(int x,int y,String e){

```
    Dimension d = new Dimension(x,y);
    setPreferredSize(d);
    setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,1));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(e));
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
}
`
```

and here's my frame

```
mainFrame = new JFrame("Shokugeki");
    mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    mainFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("src/drawable/saitama.png").getImage());
    mainFrame.setContentPane(setIcon);
    mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(list, BorderLayout.EAST);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(opt1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    mainFrame.setSize(800,500);
```

Comment: Did some one forget to call `super.paintXxx` or is some one plaing around with the clipping rectangles?

Comment: sorry but it is my first time working with gui, how should I override paintX?, what should I put in there?

Comment: Generally speaking, without a runnable example of what you're doing that demonstrates your problem it's all just guess work

Comment: just edited my question, I forgot to add my code

Comment: setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,1)); is your problem, swing doesn't know how to handle alpha based colors when set as the background color

Comment: is there other way to set my panels transparency? thanks for responding

Comment: setOpaque will make it transparent (pass in false)